# Cloth poster- attach to board

Tags: presentation, poster

I printed a poster on cloth for easy travel. Now the conference says that they will provide Velcro patches that attaches well on paper only. What kind of tape should I bring with me?

Comment: You could try and "stitch" some small pieces of cardboard to the backside of the corners and glue paper to it. Then you could use their velcro. However, I would contact the organizers and inquire if there is a solution.

Comment: Magnets could be a solution if the boards are metallic or have metal frames.

Comment: Visit your local hobby/craft/sewing store for something like this https://www.amazon.com/velcro-fabric/s?k=velcro+for+fabric